# OpenModelica: How to model plug flow for multi substance fluid medium?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am a total beginner with OpenModelica and have maybe some fundamental questions that more experienced user could probably answer easily.

Some words about the background for application for which OpenModelica is planned to be used. Target is to create a minimalistic model of the paper machine short circulation by simplifying real life components so that they are mostly just open and closed mixing volumes, pipes and valves. The former section would be splitter for the solids components (fiber and filler) in a stream as a function of retention aid concentration in the flow. Based on the simple retention model solid components are divided to two parts, one forwarding to the press section and rest returning to the wire pit being an open vessel and having overflow.

At least I didn't find directly a suitable Medium model that would be able to represent three different substances and one trace substance. Substances being water, fibers and filler. Retention aid would be a trace substance since the volume flow is really small compared to the other substances. To keep things simple the fibers and filler are assumed behave like water. The accuracy of the simulation is not the key in this exercise. The main point is to trace mass fractions of water, fiber and filler in different part of the process and demonstrate some dynamic behavior the short circulation is introducing in the operation point changes.

I managed to stitch together a medium model by borrowing ideas from different medium models that is currently supporting the three substances and a simple simulation model (source, tanks, static pipes and sink) seems to work in a reasonable manner .

To demonstrate the dynamics of the target process the model should also simulate transport delays in the pipe lines for substances. The static pipe model does not take that into account. I found in the Buildings library the plugFlowPipe model (used with district heat applications) and by looking the models code it should work with multi substance mediums derived from the PartialMedium model as long as the "water" is one of the independent substances (checks the existence of the name "water"). Since the Buildings library does not support the 4.0.0 of Modelica I had to go back to the version 3.2.3 to use the Buildings library.

The PlugFlowPipe seems to be a challenging model to get work correctly. The simulation ends with error complaining "Error solving nonlinear system....". The Transformation debugger messages are such that I could not figure out what is actually the problem.

I will attach here the medium model (SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2) and the simulation model (delay_test_05c.mo). In addition of those the Buildings library version 8.1.0 is used. Sorry, I couldn't attach those as attachments so I will post them after the question...

I hope that someone can point out what is the problem either with medium model or with the simulation model that causes the solver error? Or alternatively give an idea how to model the plug flow characteristics in another way in openmodelica for the multi substance media. Thank you very much already beforehand!

MODEL FOR MEDIUM

```
// file: SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2.mo


package SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2

  import Modelica = Modelica;


  // EXTENDING FROM A CLASS
  // **************************


  extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium(
      final ThermoStates = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.IndependentVariables.pTX,
      final singleState = true,
      final reducedX = true,
      final fixedX = false,
      reference_X=fill(1/nX,nX),
      mediumName="SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2",
      substanceNames={"water","fiber","filler"},
      extraPropertiesNames=fill("", 0)
     
      //extraPropertiesNames={"reta"}
      );

  // SPECIFY CONSTANTS
  // *********************************

  constant SpecificHeatCapacity cp_const=4184  "Constant specific heat capacity at constant pressure";
  constant SpecificHeatCapacity cv_const=4184  "Constant specific heat capacity at constant volume";
  constant Density d_const=995.586 "Constant density";
  constant DynamicViscosity eta_const=1.e-3 "Constant dynamic viscosity";
  constant ThermalConductivity lambda_const=0.598 "Constant thermal conductivity";
  constant VelocityOfSound a_const=1484 "Constant velocity of sound";
  constant Temperature T_min=273 "Minimum temperature valid for medium model";
  constant Temperature T_max=373 "Maximum temperature valid for medium model";
  constant Temperature T0=273.15 "Zero enthalpy temperature";




// defining fluid constants for substances
  import Modelica.Media.Water.ConstantPropertyLiquidWater.simpleWaterConstants;

  constant Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.Basic.FluidConstants[3]
    simpleWaterConstants(
    each chemicalFormula="H2O",
    each structureFormula="H2O",
    each casRegistryNumber="7732-18-5",
    each iupacName="oxidane",
    each molarMass=0.018015268);



  //constant MolarMass MM_const "Molar mass";
  // Molarmasses are defined for substances, just giving same values for all
  constant Real MM_const_fiber = 0.018015268;
  constant Real MM_const_filler = 0.018015268;
  constant Real MM_const_water = 0.018015268;

  constant MolarMass[nX] MMX ={MM_const_fiber, MM_const_filler, MM_const_water} "Molar mass";


  // THERMODYNAMIC STATE
  // **********************


  redeclare record extends ThermodynamicState "Thermodynamic state"
    AbsolutePressure p "Absolute pressure of medium";
    Temperature T "Temperature of medium";

    // bring in the substances
    MassFraction[nX] X(start=reference_X) "Mass fractions (= (component mass)/total mass  m_i/m)"; 

  end ThermodynamicState;



  // MODEL BaseProperties
  // ********************

  redeclare replaceable model extends BaseProperties(
    T(stateSelect=if preferredMediumStates then StateSelect.prefer else StateSelect.default),
    p(stateSelect=if preferredMediumStates then StateSelect.prefer else StateSelect.default),
    Xi(each stateSelect = if preferredMediumStates then StateSelect.prefer else StateSelect.default),
    final standardOrderComponents = true) "Base properties"

  equation
    assert(T >= T_min and T <= T_max, "
      Temperature T (= " + String(T) + " K) is not
      in the allowed range (" + String(T_min) + " K <= T <= " + String(T_max) + " K)
      required from medium model \"" + mediumName + "\".
    ");

    // h = cp_const*(T-T0);
    h = specificEnthalpy_pTX(
            p,
            T,
            X);
    u = cv_const*(T - T0);
    d = d_const;
    R = 0;
    //MM = MM_const;
    MM = molarMass(state);
    state.T = T;
    state.p = p;
    state.X = if fixedX then reference_X else X;

    annotation (Documentation(info="<html>
<p>
This is the most simple incompressible medium model, where
specific enthalpy h and specific internal energy u are only
a function of temperature T and all other provided medium
quantities are assumed to be constant.
Note that the (small) influence of the pressure term p/d is neglected.
</p>
</html>"));
  end BaseProperties;

  // DECLARE FUNCTIONS
  // *******************


  //-------------------
  redeclare function setState_pTX
    "Return thermodynamic state from p, T, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input Temperature T "Temperature";
    input MassFraction X[:]=reference_X "Mass fractions";
    output ThermodynamicState state "Thermodynamic state record";
  algorithm
    //state := ThermodynamicState(p=p, T=T);

    // take into account substances
    state := if size(X,1) == 0 then ThermodynamicState(p=p,T=T,X=reference_X)
        else if size(X,1) == nX then ThermodynamicState(p=p,T=T, X=X)
        else ThermodynamicState(p=p,T=T, X=cat(1,X,{1-sum(X)}));   // when reduceX = true

  end setState_pTX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function setState_phX
    "Return thermodynamic state from p, h, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input SpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy";
    input MassFraction X[:]=reference_X "Mass fractions";
    output ThermodynamicState state "Thermodynamic state record";
  algorithm

    state := if size(X,1) == 0 then ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = T0 + h / cp_const, X=X)
         else if size(X,1) == nX then ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = T0 + h / cp_const, X=X)
         else ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = T0 + h / cp_const, X=cat(1,X,{1-sum(X)}));

  end setState_phX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare replaceable function setState_psX
    "Return thermodynamic state from p, s, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input SpecificEntropy s "Specific entropy";
    input MassFraction X[:]=reference_X "Mass fractions";
    output ThermodynamicState state "Thermodynamic state record";
  algorithm
    //state := ThermodynamicState(p=p, T=Modelica.Math.exp(s/cp_const +
    //  Modelica.Math.log(reference_T)))
    //  "Here the incompressible limit is used, with cp as heat capacity";

    // take into account substances
    state := if size(X,1) == 0 then ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = Modelica.Math.exp(s / cp_const + Modelica.Math.log(reference_T)), X=X)
             else if size(X,1) == nX then ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = Modelica.Math.exp(s / cp_const + Modelica.Math.log(reference_T)), X=X)
             else ThermodynamicState(p = p, T = Modelica.Math.exp(s / cp_const + Modelica.Math.log(reference_T)), X=cat(1,X,{1-sum(X)}));
  end setState_psX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function setState_dTX
    "Return thermodynamic state from d, T, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input Density d "Density";
    input Temperature T "Temperature";
    input MassFraction X[:]=reference_X "Mass fractions";
    output ThermodynamicState state "Thermodynamic state record";
  algorithm
    assert(false,
      "Pressure can not be computed from temperature and density for an incompressible fluid!");
  end setState_dTX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends setSmoothState
    "Return thermodynamic state so that it smoothly approximates: if x > 0 then state_a else state_b"
  algorithm
    state := ThermodynamicState(p=Media.Common.smoothStep(
            x,
            state_a.p,
            state_b.p,
            x_small), T=Media.Common.smoothStep(
            x,
            state_a.T,
            state_b.T,
            x_small));
  end setSmoothState;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends dynamicViscosity "Return dynamic viscosity"

  algorithm
    eta := eta_const;
  end dynamicViscosity;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends thermalConductivity
    "Return thermal conductivity"

  algorithm
    lambda := lambda_const;
  end thermalConductivity;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends pressure "Return pressure"

  algorithm
    p := state.p;
  end pressure;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends temperature "Return temperature"

  algorithm
    T := state.T;
  end temperature;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends density "Return density"

  algorithm
    d := d_const;
  end density;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificEnthalpy "Return specific enthalpy"

  algorithm
    h := cp_const*(state.T - T0);
  end specificEnthalpy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificHeatCapacityCp
    "Return specific heat capacity at constant pressure"

  algorithm
    cp := cp_const;
  end specificHeatCapacityCp;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificHeatCapacityCv
    "Return specific heat capacity at constant volume"

  algorithm
    cv := cv_const;
  end specificHeatCapacityCv;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends isentropicExponent "Return isentropic exponent"

  algorithm
    gamma := cp_const/cv_const;
  end isentropicExponent;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends velocityOfSound "Return velocity of sound"

  algorithm
    a := a_const;
  end velocityOfSound;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function specificEnthalpy_pTX
    "Return specific enthalpy from p, T, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input Temperature T "Temperature";
    input MassFraction X[nX] "Mass fractions";
    output SpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy";
  algorithm
    h := cp_const*(T - T0);
    annotation (Documentation(info="<html>
<p>
This function computes the specific enthalpy of the fluid, but neglects the (small) influence of the pressure term p/d.
</p>
</html>"));
  end specificEnthalpy_pTX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function temperature_phX
    "Return temperature from p, h, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input SpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy";
    input MassFraction X[nX] "Mass fractions";
    output Temperature T "Temperature";
  algorithm
    T := T0 + h/cp_const;
  end temperature_phX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function density_phX "Return density from p, h, and X or Xi"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input AbsolutePressure p "Pressure";
    input SpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy";
    input MassFraction X[nX] "Mass fractions";
    output Density d "Density";
  algorithm
    d := density(setState_phX(
            p,
            h,
            X));
  end density_phX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificInternalEnergy
    "Return specific internal energy"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  algorithm
    //  u := cv_const*(state.T - T0) - reference_p/d_const;
    u := cv_const*(state.T - T0);
    annotation (Documentation(info="<html>
<p>
This function computes the specific internal energy of the fluid, but neglects the (small) influence of the pressure term p/d.
</p>
</html>"));
  end specificInternalEnergy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificEntropy "Return specific entropy"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  algorithm
    s := cv_const*Modelica.Math.log(state.T/T0);
  end specificEntropy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificGibbsEnergy
    "Return specific Gibbs energy"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  algorithm
    g := specificEnthalpy(state) - state.T*specificEntropy(state);
  end specificGibbsEnergy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends specificHelmholtzEnergy
    "Return specific Helmholtz energy"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  algorithm
    f := specificInternalEnergy(state) - state.T*specificEntropy(state);
  end specificHelmholtzEnergy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends isentropicEnthalpy "Return isentropic enthalpy"
  algorithm
    h_is := cp_const*(temperature(refState) - T0);
  end isentropicEnthalpy;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends isobaricExpansionCoefficient
    "Returns overall the isobaric expansion coefficient beta"
  algorithm
    beta := 0.0;
  end isobaricExpansionCoefficient;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends isothermalCompressibility
    "Returns overall the isothermal compressibility factor"
  algorithm
    kappa := 0;
  end isothermalCompressibility;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends density_derp_T
    "Returns the partial derivative of density with respect to pressure at constant temperature"
  algorithm
    ddpT := 0;
  end density_derp_T;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends density_derT_p
    "Returns the partial derivative of density with respect to temperature at constant pressure"
  algorithm
    ddTp := 0;
  end density_derT_p;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends density_derX
    "Returns the partial derivative of density with respect to mass fractions at constant pressure and temperature"
  algorithm
    dddX := fill(0, nX);
  end density_derX;

  //-------------------
  redeclare function extends molarMass "Return the molar mass of the medium"
  algorithm
    //MM := MM_const;
    MM := 1/sum(state.X[j]/MMX[j] for j in 1:size(state.X,1));
  end molarMass;



// functions that have been adopted from class PARTIALMIXTUREMEDIUM

// -----------------
  replaceable function gasConstant
    "Return the gas constant of the mixture (also for liquids)"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input ThermodynamicState state "Thermodynamic state";
    output SI.SpecificHeatCapacity R "Mixture gas constant";
   
  algorithm
    R := 0;
  end gasConstant;

// -----------------
  function moleToMassFractions "Return mass fractions X from mole fractions"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input SI.MoleFraction moleFractions[:] "Mole fractions of mixture";
    input MolarMass[:] MMX "Molar masses of components";
    output SI.MassFraction X[size(moleFractions, 1)]
      "Mass fractions of gas mixture";
  protected
    MolarMass Mmix=moleFractions*MMX "Molar mass of mixture";
  algorithm
    for i in 1:size(moleFractions, 1) loop
      X[i] := moleFractions[i]*MMX[i]/Mmix;
    end for;
    annotation (smoothOrder=5);
  end moleToMassFractions;

// -----------------
  function massToMoleFractions "Return mole fractions from mass fractions X"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
    input SI.MassFraction X[:] "Mass fractions of mixture";
    input SI.MolarMass[:] MMX "Molar masses of components";
    output SI.MoleFraction moleFractions[size(X, 1)]
      "Mole fractions of gas mixture";
  protected
    Real invMMX[size(X, 1)] "Inverses of molar weights";
    SI.MolarMass Mmix "Molar mass of mixture";
  algorithm
    for i in 1:size(X, 1) loop
      invMMX[i] := 1/MMX[i];
    end for;
    Mmix := 1/(X*invMMX);
    for i in 1:size(X, 1) loop
      moleFractions[i] := Mmix*X[i]/MMX[i];
    end for;
    annotation (smoothOrder=5);
  end massToMoleFractions;


end SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2;
```

SIMULATION MODEL USING THE MEDIUM JA PLUG FLOW COMPONENT

```
// file: delay_test_05c.mo

model delay_test_05c
  replaceable package Medium = SimpleMachineStockMedium_323_v2; // constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium "Medium in the component";
 
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank_A (
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    X_start = {0.8, 0.1, 0.1},
    crossArea = 5,
    height = 10,
    level(fixed = true, start = 3),
    m_flow_nominal=20,
    nPorts = 3,
    portsData = {
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 0),
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 1),
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 1)
      },
    use_portsData = true
   
  )
   annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-36, -6}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
 
 
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank_B (
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    X_start = {0.4, 0.4, 0.2},
    crossArea = 5,
    height = 10,
    level(fixed = true, start = 2.5),
    m_flow_nominal=10,
    nPorts = 2,
    portsData = {
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 1),
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 2)
     
      },
    use_portsData = true)
      annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {52, 26}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
 
 
 
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank_C (
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    X_start = {0.3, 0.3, 0.4},
    crossArea = 5,
    height = 10,
    level(fixed = true, start = 2.5),
    m_flow_nominal=10,
    nPorts = 2,
    portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 1),
      Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.3, height = 2)
      },
      use_portsData = true
      )
      annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {54, -48}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT Sink_B( redeclare package Medium = Medium, use_p_in = false, nPorts = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {162, 2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT Sink_C (redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 273, p = 101325, nPorts = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {184, -64}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T source_A(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    T = 320, X = {0.9, 0.05, 0.05}, m_flow = 20,
    nPorts = 1, use_T_in = false, use_X_in = false, use_m_flow_in = false
  ) 
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-138, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe_A_to_B(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    allowFlowReversal = false,
    diameter = 0.3,
    height_ab = 0,
    length = 5)
    annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {14, -8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(allowFlowReversal = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-86, 88}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe tank_B_to_sink(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    allowFlowReversal = false,
    diameter = 0.3,
    height_ab = 0,
    length = 5) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe tank_C_to_sink(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    allowFlowReversal = false,
    diameter = 0.3,
    height_ab = 0,
    length = 5) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {118, -60}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe staticPipe_Source_to_A(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    allowFlowReversal = false,
    diameter = 0.3,
    height_ab = 0,
    length = 5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-92, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Fluid.FixedResistances.PlugFlowPipe plugFlowPipe_A_to_C(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    T_start_in(displayUnit = "K") =323.15,
    T_start_out(displayUnit = "K") =323.15, cPip = 500,
    dIns = 0.05,
    dh = 0.5, initDelay = false,
    kIns = 0.028,
    length = 100,
    m_flow_nominal = 10,
    m_flow_start = 0,
    nPorts = 1, rhoPip = 8000, thickness = 0.0032) 
    annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, -62}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  // HEAT SINK FOR PLUG FLOW PIPE
  Buildings.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature heatSink(T(displayUnit = "K") = 283.15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-98, -58}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(source_A.ports[1], staticPipe_Source_to_A.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-128, -20}, {-102, -20}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(staticPipe_Source_to_A.port_b, tank_A.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-82, -20}, {-68, -20}, {-68, -42}, {-36, -42}, {-36, -26}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
 
  connect(tank_A.ports[2], pipe_A_to_B.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-36, -26}, {-30, -26}, {-30, -38}, {-8, -38}, {-8, -8}, {4, -8}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe_A_to_B.port_b, tank_B.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{24, -8}, {52, -8}, {52, 6}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
 
  connect(tank_B.ports[2], tank_B_to_sink.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{52, 6}, {60, 6}, {60, 0}, {100, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(tank_B_to_sink.port_b, Sink_B.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{120, 0}, {132, 0}, {132, 2}, {172, 2}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));

  connect(tank_A.ports[3], plugFlowPipe_A_to_C.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-36, -26}, {-32, -26}, {-32, -62}, {-20, -62}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(plugFlowPipe_A_to_C.ports_b[1], tank_C.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -62}, {12, -62}, {12, -86}, {52, -86}, {52, -68}, {54, -68}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(plugFlowPipe_A_to_C.heatPort, heatSink.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-10, -52}, {-66, -52}, {-66, -58}, {-88, -58}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
 
  connect(tank_C.ports[2], tank_C_to_sink.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{54, -68}, {64, -68}, {64, -82}, {86, -82}, {86, -60}, {108, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(tank_C_to_sink.port_b, Sink_C.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{128, -60}, {152, -60}, {152, -64}, {194, -64}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3"), Buildings(version = "8.1.0")),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-160, 100}, {200, -100}})),
    version = "");

end delay_test_05c;
```

Comment: The latest (unreleased) versions of Modelica Buildings Library support MSL 4.0.0. You can download it from GitHub: https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings

Comment: Still struggling with PlugFlowPipe component. Ended up copying the plugflowpipe example and modifying that to test the medium model. The follow-up for this question is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922397/openmodelica-building-libary-using-plugflowpipe-component

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code in Dymola 2022x with a few minor modifications:

1. I'm using the latest Modelica Buildings (v. 9.0.0) code from GitHub which supports MSL 4.0.0 and in which the downstream connector of `PlugFlowPipe` has been changed to a scalar port (simply delete connections in you model and re-connect the pipe).
2. In the model annotation of `delay_test_5c.mo` refer to `Modelica(version="4.0.0")` and  `Buildings(version="9.0.0")`
3. In your medium model in `BaseProperties` you assign the parameter `R`. This should be `R_s` instead

With these changes your simulation model runs without errors or warnings (apart from some un-initialized variables).

Comment: Excellent. I will try the new version of the Buildings library (MSL 4.0.0) and return back to the 4.0.0 version of the Medium.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Changed to new version of MSL and Buildings library. Depending on the initialization values the simulation crashes immediately in two different ways:
`Fatal error on line 32, column 10: tag mismatch`

The other common error below is probably related to the initialization values

`DASKR--  AT T (=R1) AND STEPSIZE H (=R2) THE                                    
      In above,  R1 =   4.8677751949403E-13   R2 =   1.1872622426684E-15
DASKR--  NONLINEAR SYSTEM SOLVER COULD NOT CONVERGE                             
DASKR--  BECAUSE IRES WAS EQUAL TO MINUS ONE  `